# Symfony passing request to function to an other controller

Tags: symfony

I try to give '$_REQUEST['vider']' to an other controller like this :

```
return $this->forward('TestBundle:Rapport:bo', array('vider' => 'vider'));
//, array ($_REQUEST['vider'] => 'vider) doesn't work too
```

But in my function Rapport:bo, $_REQUEST['vider'] is null, i give it in the array, where i failed ?

edit : 
my Rapport:bo function :

```
public function boAction(Request $request) {
var_dump($_REQUEST['vider']); // is null
if ( isset($_REQUEST['vider']) ) ) {
        var_dump('test');
    }

}
```

Comment: [Forwarding a request from one controller method to another controller method](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ci2p/forwarding-a-request-from-one-controller-method-to-another-controller-method)

Comment: Reading the docs can also help. :)

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

Comment: i have read the doc, and this doc do the array like my example

Comment: Can you please paste `TestBundle:Rapport:bo` function?

Comment: yes i edit my post for paste my rapport bo function

Comment: Ygg69 do you still have issue? read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819526/getting-post-request-on-symfony2

Comment: yes i resolve with $request->query->get("yourkey")  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
public function boAction($vider) {
    your logic...
```

Comment: anyway in symfony you can get request with: $request->query->get("yourkey") for GET requests or $request->request->get("yourkey") for POST request

Comment: with $request->query->get("yourkey")  that work nice thank you :)